# How to write Hibernate HQL query which remove all "grand children" elements?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have schools, which contains groups, which contains students.

I would like to remove all students from specific school.

In SQL I can write the following query:

```
DELETE FROM students1 
WHERE students1.group_id IN 
      (SELECT id FROM group1 WHERE group1.school_id = :school_id)
```

How to transform this SQL query to Hibernate HQL?

I use H2 database engine.

(My real query is more complex and simple cascade deletion of school is not suitable for me).

Comment: Hmm, are you looking for  a shortcut. Because you can convert this query directly to HQL. Hql does support IN condition.

Comment: @doc_180 In HQL I tried `students.group.school.id` but this does not work. Java Table classes has relation for student: @ManyToOne     @JoinColumn(name = "group") private Group group;
In case of SQL I can simply use ids, but in java classes I should refer using class names, I have not do this before, but it seems to me that this is frequent task and should have trivial solution

Comment: Yes there is a trivial solution. Do not use student.group.school.id. Since there is a relationship between entities, directly use the entities in the in clause. Student.group in (select g from group  where school in (select s from school))

Comment: @doc_180 thanks! your comment helps me to find the solution, I posted it below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The working script follows:

```
DELETE FROM Student AS s
WHERE s IN
    (SELECT s FROM Student AS s WHERE s.group IN
        (SELECT g FROM Group AS g WHERE g.school IN
            (SELECT s FROM School s WHERE s.id = :schoolId)))
```

Thanks to comments of doc_180

Comment: something like this worked for me: `delete from TableName where ColumnName in (select id from Table ...)`

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `JOIN` (either explicit or implicit) in Hibernate's bulk queries (like deletes) currently, but you can use them in subqueries, something like this:

```
DELETE FROM Student st
WHERE st IN (
    SELECT st 
    FROM School s JOIN s.groups g JOIN g.students st
    WHERE s = :s
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 String hql="delete from Student where group.school=:school";
 session.createQuery(hql).setParameter("school", schoolObject).executeUpdate();
```

Comment: org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter is thrown with message "Syntax error in SQL statement..."