# hibernate simple query with join not working

Tags: hibernate

I'm trying to delete some BlRelation in my database using hibernate.

Unfortunately the query does not work. Could you please help me on this ? I know it should be quite straightforward ...

```
delete r FROM BlRelation where r.elementId.blProvider.providerId = 1
```

Thanks !

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299579/how-to-write-hibernate-hql-query-which-remove-all-grand-children-elements

Answer (score 1):

Please provide more details about your mapping, without it I am only guessing. But try this:

```
delete FROM BlRelation where elementId.blProvider.providerId = 1
```

Also is `elementId` a field of `BlProvider` type? I guess it is named `element`, so it should have been:

```
delete FROM BlRelation where element.blProvider.providerId = 1
```

Finally if `element` is in *one-to-many* or *many-to-many* relationship with `BlProvider` (it is of collection type), you will need some more complicated query.

Comment: Hi Tomasz, elementId is an Element Object that contains a BlProvider object

Answer (score 1):

Quote from the [reference manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#batch-direct):

> The pseudo-syntax for UPDATE and DELETE statements is: ( UPDATE |
>   DELETE ) FROM? EntityName (WHERE where_conditions)?.
>
> Some points to note:
>
> - [...]
> - No joins, either implicit or explicit, can be specified in a bulk HQL query. Sub-queries can be used in the where-clause, where the
>     subqueries themselves may contain joins.

You could just use a subquery, or simply get the entities in the session and use `session.delete()` to delete them.

Here's a subquery that would probably work:

```
delete from BlRelation r where r.id in 
  (select r2.id from BlRelation r2 where r2.elementId.blProvider.providerId = 1)
```